# java StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: 77040000, what the ObjectInputStream expects?

Tags: java, serialization

i'm working on a network java code, and i can't seem to understand what are the prerequisites an ObjectInputStream needs to interpret bytes.
Here is a part of the code :

```
InputStream is = /* creation of the stream */
ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(is);
System.out.println(in.readInt()); // the exception is thrown here
```

exception and stack trace :

```
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: 77040000
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readBlockHeader(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.refill(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readInt(Unknown Source)
```

sending code :

```
OutputStream os = /* creation of output stream */
out = new ObjectOutputStream(os);
out.writeInt(1);
out.flush();
```

now the interesting part, when i replace "in.readInt()" with a manual reading of "is", when i pring the bytes i got :
-84 -19 0 5 119 4 0 0 0 1
i googled serialization protocols and it seems to mean :
    "-84 -19" -> serialization protocol magic numbers
    "0 5" -> version
    "119" -> type of data (TC_BLOCKDATA)
    "0 0 0 1" -> my integer = 1

so, the invalid type code "77040000" is the hexadecimal for the "119 4 0 0" part.

at this point, i don't know where to search, the ObjectInputStream seems to not be able to understand the protocol.

the input stream is custom, here is part of its code:

```
@Override
public int read() throws IOException {
    byte[] bytes = new byte[4];
    if(read(bytes, 0, 4) != 4)
        return -1;
    else
        return bytes[0] << 24 | (bytes[1] & 0xFF) << 16 | (bytes[2] & 0xFF) << 8 | (bytes[3] & 0xFF);
}

@Override
public int read(byte[] b) throws IOException {
    return read(b, 0, available());
}

@Override
public int read(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < len; i++){
        if(!isReady())
            return i == 0 ? -1 : i;
        b[i+off] = data[offset++];
    }
    return i;
}

@Override
public int available() throws IOException {
    if(isReady())
        return length - offset;
    else
        return -1;
}
```

Comment: Your first read() method duplicates DataInputStream.readInt(). The second one is redundant. The third one ditto. This code isn't as magical as you seem to think.

Answer (score 1):

Your `read()` method is broken.  It is supposed to return a single byte.  You should read the javadoc for InputStream thoroughly if you intend to write your own implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are right, i was reading the ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readBlockHeader implementation when i realized that it uses read() to get a byte.
The fact read() returns an integer made me implement it to read 4 bytes...
I should have read more thorougly the javadoc of InputStream.

Thanks for your help !